# How to create top 5 and bottom 5 column in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with revenues of channels (across multiple dates). I want to group the table by channel, and rank the top 2 channels as ('Top 2') in a separate column. And the bottom 2 channels as ('Bottom 2') in the same column.

My code:

```
SELECT
  channel,
  SUM(`gross_revenue_usd`) as sum_gross_revenue
FROM table
GROUP BY channel
ORDER BY SUM(`gross_revenue_usd`) DESC
```

I have the right order. But I cant understand how to make a new column which labels the top 2 and bottom 2 channel.

This is how it should look like:

I'm also attaching a picture

[image: output picture]

Anyone can guide me how to do that. 
I need this new column to create a filter in a visualization tool that I use.

Comment: very hard to answer a question like this without some example inputs and expected output

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: What is the output you're expecting?

Comment: have added that to question.

Comment: Why on earth are you posting a screenshot of an ASCII table, instead of posting it as plain text in a code block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use windowing functions and a case statement to do this like so:

```
SELECT channel, sum_gross_revenue,
       CASE 
         WHEN ASCORD <= 2 THEN 'BOTTOM 2' 
         WHEN DESCORD <= 2 THEN 'TOP 2'
         ELSE ''
       END AS Ranking
FROM (
  SELECT channel, sum_gross_revenue,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM_GROSS_REVENUE ASC) AS ASCORD,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM_GROSS_REVENUE DESC) AS DESCORD
  FROM (
    SELECT
      channel,
      SUM(`gross_revenue_usd`) as sum_gross_revenue
    FROM table
    GROUP BY channel
  ) A
) B
ORDER BY SUM(`gross_revenue_usd`) DESC
```

note: I used 2 sub-queries to make this clearer -- It can be written with only one sub-query.

Comment: they are column names in the sub query B @wallyk -- isn't that clear?

Comment: is there any substitute for row_number? Unfortunately this function does not exist in my mysql environment (im using it in a visualization tool)

Comment: @HamzaKhalid what version of mysql are you using?

Comment: 5.6.28-76.1-56. This version

Comment: @HamzaKhalid You could use LIMIT twice to select the first two and the last two and left join back to those results to display the string you needed when the join was non null

Comment: Is there a way in which I can just add another column creating an index (1,2,3,4,5...)

Comment: I can then use logic (case when statements) to do my job

Comment: I found the best way to order DESC, and limit to 5. Then order ASC, and limit to 5. And then do a union.

Answer (score 1):

I would write this with `case` logic:

```
select channel,
       sum(gross_revenue_usd) as sum_gross_revenue,
       (case when row_number() over (order by sum(gross_revenue_usd) desc) <= 2
             then 'TOP 2'
             when row_number() over (order by sum(gross_revenue_usd) asc) <= 2
             then 'BOTTOM 2'
         end) as ranking
from table
group by channel
order by sum_gross_revenue desc;
```

Notes:

- This does not distinguish ties.  So channels with the same revenue could have different `ranking` values.
- If there are fewer than 4 channels, then `TOP` dominates.

EDIT:

In older versions of MySQL, pretty much your only hope with a reasonable query is to use variables:

```
select channel,
       sum(gross_revenue_usd) as sum_gross_revenue,
       (case when seqnum <= 2
             then 'TOP 2'
             when seqnum >= @rn - 1
             then 'BOTTOM 2'
         end) as ranking
from (select channel, sum_gross_revenue,
             (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum
      from (select channel,
                   sum(gross_revenue_usd) as sum_gross_revenue
            from table
            group by channel
            order by sum_gross_revenue desc
           ) c cross join
           (select @rn := 0) params
     ) t
```

Comment: @Hogan . . . Your answer has two levels of unnecessary subqueries and defines extra column aliases.

Comment: the function row_number does not exits in my mysql environment that i'm using (its within the visualization tool).

Comment: would you have any substitute for row_number

Comment: @HamzaKhalid . . . You accepted an answer that uses `row_number()`.